# Moving from one's spot after Kedusha

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, kedusha-prayer

After standing still for [Kedusha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kedushah), some people move after saying [Yimloich](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kedushah), whereas others wait until after the Chazan says Hokail Hakodoish. What is the correct way?

Comment: Awfully similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29655

Answer (score 11):

Per Aruch Hashulchan Siman 95:5 in the name of the Elya Rabbah it is proper that the feet should remain together after Kedusha until Hakel Hakodesh.

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7705&st=&pgnum=172&hilite=

Rav Shlomo Zalmen Auerbach Zatzal (Halichos Shlomo, Tefilah, Perek 8: Ha'arah 60) maintains that on Rosh Hashana and Yom Kippur when there is a long time between Kedusha and HaKel Hakadosh, it isn't necessary to stand until HaKel Hakadosh

Comment: Good thing too, because the next time HaKeil HaKadosh is said is in Maariv following Yom Kippur! :)

Comment: Of course, Aruch HaShulchan and Elya Rabbah followed the Nusach Ashkenaz text ...

Comment: I didn't see the Elya Rabbah, but the Aruch haShulchan does not say "must", he says it's "good" to keep your feet together during kedusha (as is the language of the mechaber in simanim 95 and 125) and it is "proper" to keep it that way until after hakel hakadosh.

Comment: I always wondered- for those who only stand that way until yimloch if that is a mistake. Since the reasoning is that's how the angels sanctify Hashem bishmei marom (Mishna Berurah95:8), that should only apply to kadosh... and baruch... and not yimloch...!?  This question would not apply to those who wait until after hakel hakadosh- since the tzibbur is still involved in general kedusha and we can still be said to be doing angelic activity.

Comment: @YDK I have your same issue. But I think it's an In Hachi Nami: you don't have to stand feet together during the extra additions on shabat and yom tov etc. The only reason I do is to not be poresh min hatzibbur. Moving after yimloch is popular enough that I don't view myself as a poreish for doing so.

Comment: @DoubleAA I once found a medrash that the malochim also say Yimloch but I don't remember the source now.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I purposefully used Shabbat additions and not yimloch as an example because IIRC some achronim view yimloch as part of the ikar kedusha, which fits in with what you say.

Comment: This is the Chabad Custom as well: http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/sefer-haminhagim/13.htm

Answer (score 5):

Tefillo Kehilchoso says that the sense of the majority of authorities is that one can move after Yimloch. He quotes (in 117) [MB 95 [8]](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=255). The reason given there not to move the feet in kedusho is because we say “keshaim shemakdishim” (as the angels sanctify). We are to learn that the angels only say up to yimloch. We stand with feet together imitating the angels.

He further says, “but 125 [9] MB” quotes sources that say one cannot speak until after Hokail Hakodosh (presumably such speech as is allowed in the repetition of the Amidah).

He quotes the Eliya Rabbo (95, 7) and the Kaf HaChaim (16) as saying you must wait until after Hokail Hakodosh.

That Yimloch is part of the praise of the angels is referred to in this [blog](http://thanbook.blogspot.co.uk/2007/08/god-king-i.html) who gives midrashic sources (see for example Psikta Rabbosi 20).

Answer (score 2):

I have heard that some say it depends what text of the siddur you're using.

In Nusach Ashkenaz, the chazzan concludes Kedusha with *L'dor vador nagid gadlecha*, "and we shall continue to sanctify You from generation to generation ..."; this is a direct flow from the responsive *kedusha*, which wouldn't finish until the chazzan completes his blessing of *hakeil hakadosh*. Thus, people should remain in place until that point.

In Nusach Sefard, the chazzan simply continues *ata kadosh v'shimcha kadosh*, which is the standard blessing without kedusha. This means that kedusha has finished, and he's starting a new thing. If so, the last line of kedusha is *yimloch*, and people can move about as soon as the chazzan begins *ata kadosh.*

Note that a community where people remain at attention longer should probably continue that practice, rather than encourage anything with might reduce proper synagogue decorum.

Comment: Interesting, considering that the minhag of aheinu b'nei eidot haMizrah is to stay in place until after hakel hakadosh. Hmmm...

Comment: Re "If so, the last line of kedusha is _yimloch_, and people can move about as soon as the chazzan begins _ata kadosh_", couldn't an individual move about after he finishes "_yimloch_" himself?

Comment: @msh210, I suppose that might be related to the debate in latter-day poskim whether "Yimloch" is communal.