# Walking during "l'dor va'dor"

Tags: minhag, shemoneh-esrei

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moving from one's spot after Kedusha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5708/moving-from-ones-spot-after-kedusha)

During kedusha everyone stands still, however I have seen a small percentage of people who start to walk again during the stanza of "l'dor va'dor" is this a question of different minhagim? If so what are the sources for the different practices and are there any other versions besides these 2?

Comment: Please note that only Nusaḥ Ashkenaz says "LeDor VaDor". All other Nusḥaoth say "Attah Kadosh".

Comment: Noted. @SethJ does this walking phenomenon take place in those minyanim as well?