# When is kedusha "over"?

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei, hefsek-interruption, kedusha-prayer

As an extension of [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/reaching-kedusha-during-silent-shemone-esre) question:

When I *daven* and am still *davening* when the *shaliach tzibbur* repeats *shmoneh esrei*, I know I am supposed to stand quietly during *kedusha* and continue with my *davening* after it is done. But when is it "done"? On the *yamim nora'im*, the *bracha* which seems to close *kedusha (hamelech hakadosh*) is not said until many paragraphs after what is usually the end, *yimloch hashem l'olam*. Does that mean that during the year, I may resume my *davening* after the "*yimloch*" line is said, or that on R"H and Y"K I should wait until the *bracha* is said before resuming?

Comment: The first answer there says the goal is to perform Shomea' ke'oneh. At which points of Kedusha would you want to be fulfilling that? I'm guessing any time you would have said something had you not been in your silent 'Amida.

Comment: @DoubleAA including amein to the bracha? and if so, is all the stuff between yimloch and the bracha of hamelech of the same status as kedusha -- ie should everyone else be standing as if kedusha wasn't over yet?

Comment: "Status of kedusha" regarding standing in place and "status of kedusha" regarding required responses are not necessarily parallel

Comment: Per @DoubleAA's last comment, I suppose this is technically not a duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5708. It's very similar, though.

Comment: @msh210 If you could get me a source that says that the rules for both applications are identical then I'd be overjoyed. I just don't know if that is the case.

Comment: Seems to me that you shouldn't be waiting for "the kedusha to be over", but rather for the Shaliach Tzibur to have finished "the first 3 berachot"... no?

Comment: @avi that may be the center of what I don't know.

Comment: I'm really confused what you aren't sure about, given my first comment above and the post you linked to. You literally link to a citation of the relevant Shulchan Arukh in your post, and it says to pause for Shomea KeOneh. What is unclear to you? Are you not sure what things you'd want to be saying if you weren't in the middle of Shemone Esrei?

Comment: Btw there's the similar parallel question about when it starts on those days (when piyyutim are often inserted) since, depending which piyyutim your community skips, there may be a very long time from the "beginning of kedusha" ובכן לך תעלה קדשה until the first verse קדוש קדוש קדוש is said.

Answer (score 3):

During the regular year, [the Chabad custom is](http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/sefer-haminhagim/13.htm#t91) to stand at attention until after the sheliach tzibbur has said ha'E-l hakadosh

According to [the footnote](http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/sefer-haminhagim/13.htm#n92):

> "The source for the above is [Eliyah Rabbah, end of sec. 95](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41130&pgnum=61) (and regarding speaking at this time see also the view of Maharil, cited in Darchei Moshe and [Eliyah Rabbah at the end of sec. 125](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41130&pgnum=75))."

I don't see why it should be any different if you're waiting to continue your silent prayer.

Comment: this is very helpful -- 2 questions remain: is this the same practice for resuming davening and does this apply on the yomim nora'im when there is a longer pause before the bracha.

Comment: @Danno: 1) I don't see why it should be any different 2) no (based on practice)

Comment: @Menachem the notion of a difference plays off DoubleAA's comment on the question that there might be 2 separate notions. And as to your note 2, does this mean that though there is black letter source for waiting till the end of the bracha, the practice on R"H and Y"K is simply not to follow that practice?

Comment: @Danno. With regards to note 2, That is discussed in the question linked by msh210. Also I just looked there and noticed that I actually commented there about this custom last year: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5708/moving-from-ones-spot-after-kedusha#comment36568_5710

Comment: There are Posekim that disagree with this Elya Raba (e.g. HaRav Haim Kanievsky).

Comment: @Menachem How can you know if it should or shouldn't be different if you haven't analyzed the reasons in your sources?

Comment: Relevant page in the Tur is missing in this scan: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14265&pgnum=206

Comment: @DoubleAA It says not to interrupt during kedusha until the end of the bracha. If you think there's a mid-amidah exception, you should explain why.

Answer (score 2):

Mishna Berura 124:1 writes that aside from לעומתם, נעריצך/נקדש, and ובדברי, all of the extra additions to Kedusha on Shabbos are not part of Kedusha and one need not listen to the chazzan for those sections. He also brings that even ימלוך is not part of Kedusha and need not be listened to according to the Mogen Avrohom.

Accordingly, the same should apply on Rosh Hashana, that the primary Kedusha is just those parts.

That which one may or may not stop to listen to the conclusion of the beracha, הקל הקדוש, is really a separate point. The Mishna Berura (66:21) explains that it has special significance as the conclusion of the first three berachos (and therefore one would answer אמן to it while in the middle of kerias shema), but it is not a part of Kedusha, which has already ended.

Answer (score 0):

Many people simply stop standing for kedusha after "ukdoshim yihallilucha selah." before beginning "baruch atah hashem haayl hakadosh" even, and this is seen clearly at least in the Chabad machzorim which say "you may be seated" after "selah" for Rosh hahsana.