Why don't we say "yimloch Hashem..." in the kedushah of birkos krias shema?
We say yimloch Hashem by the other kedushos by chazaras hashatz and by uva letzion (well, really we say Hashem yimloch...)
What's different about the kedushah here?

It may just not be part of kedusha https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/100418/759 After all it's not something the angles say

I don't know why you gloss over the difference between ה ימלך and ימלך ה

We do say Hahem Yimloch in the bracha after shema. Not sure if that's relevant, though
